# What is the equation for calculating an investment with compounding interest and periodic contribution?

Tags: linear-algebra, economics, programming

I am a begginner C# programmer working on a investment calculator as a personal project. I have not done much math in the last 15 years, please help.

The parameters are:
Principal - the original sum deposited in the account, lets say 1000
Interest - for example 5(%). This can be calculated monhly or yearly
Compound Interval -  Years for the investment to grow, like 10 years
intervalsInAYear - how many times in a year the interest is calculated(12 for monthly)
Additional contribution, monthly or yearly, for example 100 per month

The equation below is what i got working, but it does not have the additional contribution:

$$endAmount = principal {\left( {1 + {{interest} \over intervalsInAYear }} \right)^{intervalsInAYear\:*\:compoundInterval}}$$

Comment: Well...I think you are using "Compound Interval" to mean two different things.  You need to specify the "compounding frequency".  If, say, we are compounding every six months, then you need the denominator in your expression to be $2$.  Then you also need to take into account the number of compounding periods.  That would be the number of compounding periods under consideration.  For instance, if you have semi-annual compounding for $5$ years then you have $10$ compounding periods.

Comment: All this stuff is pretty well documented on line...see, e.g., [this](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/compoundinterest.asp).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. intervalsInAYear is now in the parameter list. What i need is the equation used to calculate the endAmount WITH montly contributions.  The equation will be featured in the application with MathJax, as a visual aid for the calculator user.

Comment: As I say, the frequency must appear in the denominator.  If, say, you  invest $100$  at a rate of $6\%$ for $5$ years compounded semi-annually, then the end result should be $100\times \left(1+\frac {.06}2\right)^{10}$.

Comment: Thank you for you message. Your formula and the one in my question do the same thing. What the question asks is what is the formula with periodic contribution.

Comment: I understand your question, but if you can't get the basic things right, there is no point looking at next steps.  Your formula does not match mine...your denominator is "CompoundInterval" which you define to be the number of years for the investment to grow.  That is not correct.

Comment: Once you have repaired your formula, there is no difficulty at all with multiple investments.  You could simply regard them as separate investments, adding up the results at the end, or (if each investment amount is equal) you could get a closed form for the sum via [Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).  The latter is computationally more elegant, but the former would allow you to vary the investment schedule over time.

Comment: You were right, there was a compoundInterval instead of interestintervalsInAYear.